# Number of databases per instance

Tags: redis, redisgraph

Is there any limitation on the number of redisgraph databases that I can create in a single redis instance?

```
GRAPH.QUERY database1 "Cypher"
```

Is there any performance issues regarding a high number of these keys?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of graphs on a single Redis server is limited by the number of keys the server can accommodate, as each graph is associated with a key.

In terms of performance, RedisGraph the module will initialise a single global thread pool which will serve all of the graph keys, obviously each graph will have its memory footprint. but this is not different than having multiple keys of different types: list, set, hash.